# Android greenDAO - Primitive data types

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator

I'd like to ask if there is a way to use primitive data types as table fields with greenDAO?
If it is, code example would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to use? I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Could you give some example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to know if I have to use objects for table columns, or I can also use primitive types. e.g. long instead Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't, at least with the provided framework. In the documentation, there's the [PropertyType](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao-generator/de/greenrobot/daogenerator/PropertyType.html) enum, which only have objects. Maybe you could, modifying the generated code, but I'm not quite sure and it seems a lot of manual work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the accepted answer points to a dead link, here's an update for GreenDao 3:

> To add support for a custom type, you can map them to one of the
>   supported types using a @Convert annotation. You also need to provide
>   a PropertyConverter implementation.

More detailed info and an example can be found here:

http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/custom-types/